# Unable to Send Data to Splunk; Keep Getting Exception Occurred 400 Client Error

Tags: exception, splunk, httpexception

I'm trying to send data to Splunk to monitor on their dashboards. I'm getting this response when I try to send it via my python script that parses JSON data, cleans it up, and sends it to Splunk. I'm certain I have the right Host, Index (HEC Token), and Port. I'm also certain that the body of my request is accurate. Any ideas on what caused this?

I've tried using a different Index. I've tried printing the response (didn't add any detail really). I'm just not sure what it could be, and I wish the exception was more specific.

Response:

```
Exception Occurred 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://splunk.url.i.am.using:8088/services/collector
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://splunk.url.i.am.using:8088/services/collector
```

Comment: Please tell us how you're attempting to send the event.  Not "via my Python script", but the actual request that goes over the wire.

Comment: In all probability, you've missed something in your "Python script". As @RichG commented: you need to share relevant portions of the script. Do you have a clear network path to Splunk from your host machine? Is https enabled? Do you have a valid HEC token?